# Want some additional help on "Pine Script for a few EMAs on multiple timeframes"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

Went through your answer on "Pine Script for a few EMAs on multiple timeframes" (Answered in Aug, 2021). It was a great effort indeed! Just wanted to know that how can I set Buy/Sell alert when the PRICE closes above or below any of the EMAs you listed? And how can it be displayed on the chart as well?
Thanks.

```
price= (close) 
longCond = crossover(price, MA_Period1) or crossover(price, MA_Period2) or crossover(price, MA_Period3)    
shortCond = crossunder(price, MA_Period1) or crossunder(price, MA_Period2) or crossunder(price, MA_Period3)
```

I was expecting to generate BUY alert when the price closes above any of the EMAs and SELL alert when closes below it.

Comment: Who are you talking to?

Answer (score 0):

To figure out if the price crossed an EMA value, you just need to find what is variable name that stores the EMA value and then use `crossover` or `crossunder` functions.

Example:

```
longCond = crossover(price, MA_Period1)  // Price crossed over MA #1
```

If you want to set an alert for that, you can use the `alertcondition()` function.

```
alertcondition(longCond, "Price crossed over MA #1")
```

If you want to show this on your chart, you can use the `plotshape()` function.

```
plotshape(longCond, "Long", shape.labelup, location.belowbar, color.green, text="Long", textcolor=color.white)
```